# Unable to use scp for file uploads in perl for secondary ethernet interface

Tags: perl, interface, scp

Hi I'm trying to use SCP to upload the files to the remote server through a perl code.

The server on which the code is being run have multiple ethernet interface(eth0,eth1,eth2)

eth0 is the default interface.

The server to which I'm trying to upload the files can only be reached by eth2 interface.

Is there something which I need to modify in the code to use that particular interface for the uploads.(eth2)

I'm using:

use Expect; #for scp

Comment: Taking care of ip/routes should be a job for your sysadmin.

Comment: @Сухой27 is there any way to add an entry to the routing table so that can route the request.Like adding a host route to the SFTP server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, check `man route/man ip` and make sure to have root credentials.

Comment: But bear in mind that routing to the same subnet over different physical interfaces is intrinsically fraught with complications. There's no guarantee of a symmetric route across your network. If it's to a different subnet then that's fine, but then you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Routing doesn't work in 'user space' it's handled by the kernel. There is nothing you can do with a perl script that will deal with that.

You need to look at your routing table, or how to configure your network interfaces on appropriate subnets.